# De-duplicating list of lists on first element only

Tags: python

I am reading raw data from a stream and get a simple list back for each row, e.g.

```
[1, "abc", 15]
```

I want to append these into a list (presume a large set of data will be read) but remove duplicates only on the first element and simply drop anything else, e.g. receiving:

```
[1, "abc", 15]
[2, "def", 12]
[1, "ghi", 6]
```

would result in

```
my_list = [ [1, "abc", 15], [2, "def", 12] ]
```

Being new to Python, what is the most efficient way of doing this. Currently I store the first element in a set then search this on every new entry, but I think this is probably not the best way, kind of like this as a test case:

```
ids = set()

my_test_list = [[1,'a',4],[2,'a',4],[3,'a',4],[1,'a',4],[1,'a',4]]
output_data = []

for i in my_test_list:
    if i[0] not in ids:
        ids.add(i[0])
        output_data.append(i)

print(output_data)
```

But didn't know if keeping two collections is the best approach in Python.

Comment: Checking a set (or equivalent) is the right approach, so if your code works you will not be able to speed it up much... unless you made a mistake elsewhere. Post your code?

Comment: *"...then search this [set]..."*: show your code. "searching" sounds fishy. I hope you used the `in` operator?

Comment: @trincot, sorry, yes I I use 'in', I just didn't know if keeping two collections and cross-checking was the best way, or whether some kind of list comprehension or iteration was the usual/better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a set like that is already a good fast solution, I can only offer a mainly *shorter* way using a dict with the first elements as keys and the whole lists as values:

```
output_data = list({i[0]: i for i in my_test_list}.values())
```

Benchmark results for 10,000 lists with 50% duplicates:

```
Round 1  Round 2  Round 3 
1245 us  1235 us  1232 us  original
 788 us   786 us   785 us  Kelly
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import timeit
from functools import partial
from random import shuffle

def original(my_test_list):
    ids = set()
    output_data = []
    for i in my_test_list:
        if i[0] not in ids:
            ids.add(i[0])
            output_data.append(i)
    return output_data

def Kelly(my_test_list):
    return list({i[0]: i for i in my_test_list}.values())

# Config
solutions = [original, Kelly]
my_test_list = [[i,'a',4] for i in range(5000)] * 2
shuffle(my_test_list)
number = 1000

# Correctness
expect = original(my_test_list)
for sol in solutions:
    result = sol(my_test_list)
    print(result == expect, sol.__name__)
print()

# Speed
tss = [[] for _ in solutions]
for r in range(3):
    print(*(f'Round {i+1} ' for i in range(r+1)))
    for sol, ts in zip(solutions, tss):
        t = timeit(partial(sol, my_test_list), number=number) / number
        ts.append(t)
        print(*('%4d us ' % (t * 1e6) for t in ts), sol.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I need to digest all of this as there's so many things I need to learn. But quickly, what is print(*()) doing? I can see it's adding white space, but I cannot find a description in a search? I also didn't realise you could pass function pointers either.

Comment: The `(...)` is a generator, the preceding `*` just unpacks the elements into the `print` call.